# Spring Batch using >= and < in Where Clause

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, spring-batch-admin

Trying hands on with Spring Batch to read data which is created only yesterday. Below is the bean I am trying to use, using JdbcPagingItemReader & SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean. However, the query isn't getting executed.

Appreciate your help!

```
<bean id="customersPagingItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT CUST_ID, CREATED " />
            <property name="fromClause" value=" from CUSTOMERS" />
            <property name="whereClause" value=" where CREATED &gt;= trunc(SYSDATE-1) and CREATED &lt; trunc(SYSDATE)" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="5" />
    <property name="fetchSize" value="5" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.yahoo.affiliationapi.api.CustomerRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error when the query is executed? Can you post any exception you see?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. When I looked at the Job Step Exit Message says - 'sortKey must be specified'

I just added the below property to the above code & it started working fine.

`<property name="sortKey" value="CUST_ID" />`

Answer (score 0):

you have to set sort key for queryProvider. 
you can refer this example:

```
@Bean
public SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean queryProvider() {
        SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean provider = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();

        provider.setSelectClause("select id, name, credit");
        provider.setFromClause("from customer");
        provider.setWhereClause("where status=:status");
        provider.setSortKey("id");

        return provider;
}
```